# Integrate 3d game functionality in Native iOS through Flutter

Tags: flutter, react-native, unity-game-engine, swiftui

I am currently trying to implement a 3d game, in which I also need nativeiOS functionality like good integration of the applePencil (like with pencilKit).

I thought about using SceneKit but as I found a lot of information that it is not that great (https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/117457) I went for Unity. I used the Unity as a library for SwiftUI (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityasaLibrary.html) which worked but one withdraw is that unity always has to be opened FullScreen and I felt uncomfortable just overlaying the unity window with SwiftUI UI elements. Furthermore as I realized that Unity as a library is not available for macOS I now have to come up with a different solution anyway.

[image]
(The background is Unity, the UI is SwiftUI)

I think about using Flutter or ReatNative and combine the modules from Unity and Native iOS there. Is that a good idea, or do you propose a different solution?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS, always use PencilKit is the best solution for user experience.

If you need PencilKit for Flutter, [library](https://pub.dev/packages/pencil_kit) is ready.